# Can a curve's unit normal vector be determined using the second derivative?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Because $$T = \frac {r'}{|r'|}$$ I was wondering whether or not it was also valid to solve for the unit normal vector with the second derivative without first solving for T: $$N = \frac {r''}{|r''|}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not. The  problem is that if you differentiate $T$, which leads to a multiple of $N$, you have to use the quotient rule, *not* just differentiate the top and bottom. You might want to try this with a simple curve like

$
( x(t), y(t) ) = (t, t^2)
$

at $t = 1$ to see that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

There is a theorem that says that if a vector function has constant length then its derivative vector will be orthogonal to it. Since **T** has constant length (because it is a unit vector) then **T'** is guaranteed to be orthogonal to **T** and hence normal to the curve.

On the other hand **r'** does not necessarily have constant length and hence **r''** doesnt have to be orthogonal to **r'** and so not normal to the curve.